# NSImageView change event handler

Tags: macos, cocoa, events, nsimageview

I'd like to catch event of image changing in my NSImageView, how can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using [KVO](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html) to monitor the `image` key. If that doesn't work, you'll probably have to subclass NSImageView and insert your logic into `setImage:` (and call super).